# Spring Boot REST API deployment on JBOSS EAP 6.2.4

Tags: spring, jboss, spring-boot

I am creating a new angular UI and a couple of web services which will be called from angular UI. I created all web services using spring boot and Spring tool suite. I did coding for angular on brackets. Everything was working good.

Now its time to move this code to production. Our production environment is Jboss EAP 6.4. I took the angular code and was successfully able to make it run on Jboss servers. But i am having issues with the RESTful web services. I converted the services to create a WAR file using the instructions in - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/fusiontables/")
public class HeatMapUploadController {

    @Autowired
    private HeatMapService mapQueryJsonService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getBoundaries(HeatMapUploadCommand uploadCommand) {
        System.out.println("Data is " + uploadCommand);
        return mapQueryJsonService.getMapQueryJson(uploadCommand);
    }
}
```

In the application.properties i added the following
server.servlet-path=/*

These are my maven dependancies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But when i call the Web Service, i am getting a 404. When i do maven package i dont get any errors and from STS if i say run on Server and select Jboss EAP 6.2.4 i dont get any errors. I see the same question is asked by quite a few others as well.

These are the only warnings i got

```
19:56:47,462 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
19:56:47,463 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
19:56:47,889 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
19:56:47,889 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)



19:56:52,391 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/chartis-services]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
19:56:52,392 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2652 ms
19:56:53,003 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
19:56:53,004 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
19:56:53,005 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
19:56:53,005 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
19:56:53,006 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
19:56:53,006 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
19:56:53,006 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
19:56:53,006 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
19:56:53,006 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
19:56:53,210 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@790420d7: startup date [Tue May 31 19:56:49 MST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
19:56:53,286 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapped "{[/fusiontables/upload],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.amex.chartis.services.controller.HeatMapUploadController.getBoundaries(com.amex.chartis.services.command.HeatMapUploadCommand)
19:56:53,288 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapped "{[/fusiontables/legend],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.amex.chartis.services.controller.HeatMapUploadController.getLegend(com.amex.chartis.services.command.HeatMapUploadCommand)
19:56:53,288 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapped "{[/fusiontables/allzips],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.amex.chartis.services.controller.HeatMapUploadController.getAllZips(com.amex.chartis.services.command.HeatMapUploadCommand)
19:56:53,289 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapped "{[/zip/byradius],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.amex.chartis.services.controller.ZipUploadController.getRadialDistance(com.amex.chartis.services.command.ZipUploadCommand)
19:56:53,295 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
19:56:53,296 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

Comment: Can you set your logging level to debug so we can get additional details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the following onStartup and it fixed the issue

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.addMapping("/*");
    super.onStartup(container);
}

private WebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation(Application.class.getName());
    return context;
}
```